# Возникает звук при переходе с Edit'а

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте, при нажатии на Enter становится активным окно Edit2, но при этом раздается звук. А при примере ниже звук не издается, но ничего в Edit написать не получается.

```
procedure TNPay.loginEditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
    if Key = #13 then
    PasswordEdit.SetFocus;
    key :=#0
end;
```

Comment: вам  нужно использовать составной оператор, вы про него в этом коде забыли. `Key` должно подменяться на `#0` в том и только в том случае, когда `Key = #13`

Comment: я даже загуглил что такое _составной оператор_ :D

Comment: Возьмите всю конструкцию после if в `begin`...`end`; Сейчас у Вас при нажатии любой клавиши - key код подменяется на `#0`